# Pythonでgrepコマンドを実行する際に変数展開する方法

Tags: python, python3, grep

以下のコードではgrepを用いて配列animalの中からtest.txt内に存在するものだけ
を出力したいのですが、おそらくgrepの出力結果を変数にうまく格納できていないのか、何度やってもエラーが発生してしまいます。解決方法がわからないため、教えていただきたいです。

```
# coding: UTF-8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
import subprocess                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

animal=["dog","cat","horse","pig","bird"]
WORD=[]
cmd="grep -c {} test.txt"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

for i in range(len(animal)):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  c=subprocess.check_output(cmd.format(animal[i]).split())                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

  if int(c) > 0:                                                                                                                                                
    WORD.append(animal[i])                                                                                                                                               

for i in range(len(WORD)):                                                                                                                               
  print("WORD[i]=%s" % WORD[i])
```

以下のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    c=subprocess.check_output(cmd.format(animal[i]).split())
  File "C:\Users\aveni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\aveni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['grep', '-c', 'pig', 'test.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.check_output`は実行したコマンドの終了コード（exit status）が0以外の場合に`CalledProcessError`を出します。`grep`は探している文字列がマッチしたときだけ終了コードが0になります。`check_output`の代わりに`run`をつかった場合はこうなります。

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess

animal = ["dog", "cat", "horse", "pig", "bird"]
WORD = []
cmd = "grep -c {} test.txt"

for ani in animal:
    c = subprocess.run(cmd.format(ani).split(), capture_output=True)
    if int(c.stdout) > 0:
        WORD.append(ani)

for w in WORD:
    print("WORD[i]=%s" % w)
```

grepコマンドで文字列があるかどうかを判別するだけなら、終了コード（c.returncode）を使うほうが良い書き方だと思います。

Comment: 無事に希望通りに動作しました！

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.check_output() を使う場合には [subprocess.CalledProcessError](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) を捕捉する事になります。

それから、これは本題とは関係がありませんが、検索語に空白文字(TAB やスペースなど)が含まれている場合、質問欄のコードではエラーが発生してしまいます。以下では検索語をシングルクォートで囲み、`subprocess.check_output()` で `shell=True` を指定しています。

```
import subprocess

animal = ['dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'pig', 'bird', 'wild boar']
WORD = []
cmd = r"grep -c '{}' test.txt"

for name in animal:
  try:
    c = subprocess.check_output(cmd.format(name), shell=True)
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError as ex:
    if ex.returncode == 1:   ## None match
      c = 0 ## c = ex.output
    elif ex.returncode == 2: ## Error occurred
      print(ex)
      break

  if int(c) > 0:
    WORD.append(name)

for i in range(len(WORD)):
  print(f'WORD[{i}] = {WORD[i]}')
```